# Upload file wocommrece

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I give 777 permission in my upload folder, but I don't know why this message is showing.

> Max upload size per file: -1MB. Max total upload size: -1MB

When I tried to upload a small size photo, it showed me

> The file "Screen Shot 2015-06-21 at 12.39.28.png" is too big.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why don't you try with a lower limit first? Like `8M`?

Comment: i try less then 1m :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [never set any of your directories to 777](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions). Change this to 755 or 750.

> Max upload size per file: -1MB. Max total upload size: -1MB

Notice that it's saying -1MB instead of 1MB. Check your `php.ini` file for `post_max_size` and/or `upload_max_filesize`. Reach out to your host if you don't know where this file is.

If you have trouble with this step, [I did find this plugin here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/increase-upload-max-filesize/). I haven't tested this plugin nor do I recommend installing this until you first try contacting your host or changing the php.ini but figured as a last resort you can try this.

Also check your `.htaccess` file if there's anything in there regarding the file size.

Comment: where i can find this php.ini and about this file .htaccess i try two times but it was not work :)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6or0lxohxq6whd/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-23%20at%2000.15.05.png?dl=0 can u check this please

Comment: Core post_max_size 512   Core upload_max_filesize 1024

Comment: something wrong inside my wordpress becz its subdomain my main domain don't have same problem but in my subdomain i can upload image its only problem after checkout when customer want to upload images :(

Comment: Try reaching out to your host on this issue. They should be able to easily resolve this for you.

Comment: Do you mean my digitalocen becz I host my self o buy cpenal and take my server my self :(